# Can I use body-parser module without installing Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using body parser after installing Express from npm. Can I use  this module without Express?

```
Const body=require("body-parser");
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can be using package [body parser](http://body-parser) without installing express

```
$ npm install body-parser
```